# How can I create List of rectangles in TypeScript?

Tags: html, typescript

How can I declare a list of rectangle type?

I have tried this way without list but didn't work:

in TypeScript file:

```
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var index = 0;
class Rectangles {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    height: number;
    width: number;
}
let rects: Array<Rectangles>;
function Load()
{
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            rects[index].x = 25 + (j * 25);
            rects[index].y = 25 + (i * 25);
            rects[index].width = 25;
            rects[index].height = 25;
            index++;
        }
    }

}

function myClick() {
    var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("canvas");
    let context: CanvasRenderingContext2D = canvas.getContext("2d");
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    index = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(rects[index].x, rects[index].y, rects[index].width, rects[index].height);
            context.fillStyle = "White";
            context.fill();
            context.lineWidth = 2;
            context.strokeStyle = "Black";
            context.stroke();
            index++;
        }
    } 
}
```

I called the function un the HTML page.

So I need to know how to declare as a list.

in c# we will do this:

```
List<Rectangle> rects = new List<Rectangle>();
```

How can I do this in TypeScript?

Comment: `let rects: Array<Rectangles> = [];` then `rects[index] = { x: 123, y: 123 ... }` and you don't really need a class here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Load()
 {
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
       let rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.x = 25 + (j * 25);
        rect.y = 25 + (i * 25);
        rect.width = 25;
        rect.height = 25;
        rects[index++;] = rect;
    }
    }
  }
```

You are almost right in creating array of rectangles. Think of this array like container and to fill container you need type of rectangle. So you have to first create rectangle then add into container which is rects in this case. Before this you need to initialize container first like rects = [].

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to explicitly use the `Array` class, try this:

```
interface Rectangle {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    height: number;
    width: number;
}

let rects: Rectangle[] = [];

function Load()
{
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            const rect: Rectangle = {
              x: 25 + (j * 25);
              y: 25 + (i * 25);
              width: 25;
              height: 25;
            }
            rects.push(rect)
            index++;
        }
    }

}
```